# copying auxiliary files

Tags: git

I am trying to git clone something but I am getting a permissions error, I have setup git with the rails installer [here](http://railsinstaller.org/) so not sure what to do here.

```
Anderss-MacBook-Pro:tmp anderskitson$ sudo git clone git@github.com:mhartl/rails_tutorial_sublime_text.git
Cloning into rails_tutorial_sublime_text...
The authenticity of host 'github.com (207.97.227.239)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,207.97.227.239' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Anderss-MacBook-Pro:tmp anderskitson$
```

I am also getting this output when running ssh-add -l

```
Anderss-MacBook-Pro:Packages anderskitson$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

Content of ssh

```
Anderss-MacBook-Pro:.ssh anderskitson$ ls
known_hosts
Anderss-MacBook-Pro:.ssh anderskitson$
```

Comment: @adamdunson I added the content of .ssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guide should help you: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

You need to generate an SSH private/public key combo and add it to github before trying to clone.